# if and else condition breaking because of array index mismatching with the column value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

I have a database table like this:

| ID | VALUE | ISEDITABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Company0 | Y |
| 1 | Company1 | N |
| 2 | Company2 | N |
| 5 | Company5 | Y |
| 99 | CompanyOther | N |

And in my react code, after making an api call(not shown in this post) to this table,the results are stored in the `sessionStorage` of the browser as `Key` and `Value` pair as shown below.

Key : `categories`

Value:

```
[{
        "id": 0,
        "value": "Company0",
        "isEditable": "Y",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/0"
            },
            "category": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "Company1",
        "isEditable": "Y",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/1"
            },
            "category": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "Company2",
        "isEditable": "Y",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/2"
            },
            "category": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/2"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "value": "Company 5",
        "isEditable": "Y",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/5"
            },
            "category": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/5"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 99,
        "value": "Company Other",
        "isEditable": "Y",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/99"
            },
            "category": {
                "href": "http://mydevserver.com:443/WebServices/api/categories/99"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Basically, it looks like the following in browser:
[image]

I have the following `actionTemplate`function in react for displaying `EDIT`, `DELETE` and `DOWNLOAD` buttons as shown below:

In the `rowData` variable, I have access to the `categoryId` by using `rowData.categoryId` which is equivalent to the `ID` column of the above table.

```
actionTemplate = (rowData: any) => (
        console.log(rowData),
        <div style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '6em'}}>
            <span>
                { JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('categories') as string)[rowData.categoryId].isEditable === 'N' ?
                   <Button icon="pi pi-trash" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} tooltip='Delete' />
                   :
                  <span>
                  <Button type='button' icon="pi pi-pencil" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(rowData, e)} tooltip='Edit'/>
                  <Button icon="pi pi-trash" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} tooltip='Delete' />
                  </span>
                
                }
               

                {
                       rowData.fullPathName !== null &&
                       <Button icon="pi pi-download" tooltip='Download' onClick={(e) => this.handleDownloadClick(rowData, e)} />
                }
            </span>
            
        </div>
       );
```

**My Requirement:**

To not show `EDIT` button when `ISEDITABLE` column is set to `N`. And show the `EDIT` button when `ISEDITABLE` column is set to `Y`.

So, I made the changes in the above function to achieve the above requirement. However, I ran into an issue when the array indexes doesn't match with the `ID` column of the above table.

For example, the above code runs fine as long as the `rowData.categoryId` = 0,1 and 2 because till `ID = 2` , it matches the array indexes. However, as soon as it reaches ID = 5 or 99, it breaks since array index position for `ID = 5` is `4` and for `ID = 99` is `5`.

Is there a workaround of this problem, other than the approach I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `categories` is an array of object so you need to using `find` to get he element you want like this:

```
{
    JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('categories') as string).find(
        category => category.id === rowData.categoryId
    )?.isEditable === 'N' ? (
        <Button
            icon="pi pi-trash"
            style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}
            tooltip="Delete"
        />
    ) : (
        <span>
            <Button
                type="button"
                icon="pi pi-pencil"
                style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}
                onClick={e => this.handleClick(rowData, e)}
                tooltip="Edit"
            />
            <Button
                icon="pi pi-trash"
                style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}
                tooltip="Delete"
            />
        </span>
    );
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the index, use `.find` to find the item you want:

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('categories') as string).find((category) => {
    return category.id === rowData.categoryId;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit my code and fit the above things there? I am wondering how would it look in my code since it is returning this line `return category.id === rowData.categoryId;`